# How to send Json as request to controller file in play framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, playframework

I would like to send json request through ajax and the same I like to parse from controllers. Please find my below code **(View part)**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectall" />
<table id="tbl" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="save" value="save" />
<div id="log"></div>
```

**JQuery part**

```
 $("#save").click(function() {       
          //get all the checked checboxex
          $('#tab input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
            //for each checked checkbox, iterate through its parent's siblings
            var array = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function() {
              return $(this).text().trim();
            }).get();
            //to print the value of array
            console.log(JSON.stringify(array))
             $.ajax({
                 type : 'POST',
                 url : '@routes.Application.save()',
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: JSON.stringify(array),
                 success : function(data) {
                    console.log("success"); 

               },
                 error : function() {

                     alert("failure")
                 }

                 });
          })
```

**Controller part**

```
public static Result saveboxes()
  {
      JsonNode json = null;
      try{
          DynamicForm dynamicForm = new DynamicForm();
            dynamicForm = dynamicForm.bindFromRequest();
            Dynamic dynamic = dynamicForm.get(); 
            json = Json.toJson(dynamic.getData());
            //String data = json.get("data").asText();
            JsonNode jsonData = Json.parse(json.asText());
         logger.info(jsonData.asText());
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }


        return null;
  }
```

I am getting null pointer exception. The view will return multiple rows of values based on user selection through checkbox. Input would be ["2","3","4"]["2","3","4"]["2","3","5"] if user select three rows. I need to get all the values in controllers. If you suggest better way than this. It would be great.

Comment: Consider using Play's JavaScript routing support.  Instead of using jQuery AJAX support, you can generate JS routers for your controllers and use those - this will handle the HTTP method type too.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the data format you are sending and it is not json format.
it should be something like this:

```
{
   [
      "2",
      "3",
      "4"
   ],
   [
      "2",
      "3",
      "4"
   ],
   [
      "2",
      "3",
      "5"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the "dataType" is not enough. You need to set the "contentType" as well. Try to add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` to your request.

It should look something like this:

```
             $.ajax({
             type : 'POST',
             url : '@routes.Application.save()',
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8,
             dataType: "json",
             data: JSON.stringify(array),
             success : function(data) {
                console.log("success"); 

           },
             error : function() {

                 alert("failure")
             }

             });
```

And make sure to choose the right charset if you don't use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Define jsRouter before script section and after that you can use it like below:

```
@scripts = {
      @helper.javascriptRouter("jsRouter")(
        controllers.routes.javascript.Application.save
      )
       <script type="application/javascript">

                   ...

                   $("#save").click(function() { 
                          ...
                          jsRouter.controllers.Application.save().ajax({
                                  cache: false,
                                  method: "POST",
                                  contentType: "application/json",
                                  data: JSON.stringify({
                                    ...
                                  }),
                                  success: function(data) {
                                    ...
                                  },
                                  error: function(data) {
                                    ...
                                  }
                           });
                   }
       </script>
}
```